# From where to study Query processing, Query optimization and Multiple Granularity protocol

Tags: databases

I am wondering about from where do I need to consult the upper said topics in a good depth in order to solve the questions intuitively. Please help me out in this regard. Please provide some video lectures from where I can learn this topics.